# Como criar pastas dentro da própria subpasta do programa?

Tags: c#

Como criar pastas dentro da própria subpasta do programa, **mesmo que o usuário deixe o programa em qualquer lugar do computador**?

Todos os meios que achei seriam com caminhos já determinados e o outro método fora em assembly, entretanto, não sou familiarizado com o assembly.

A ideia é que o programa verifique se a pasta existe e caso exista, verifica se há arquivos dentro, após isto, o programa irá copiar todo o conteúdo e jogar para uma outra pasta pré-definida.

Comment: tenta obter o caminho do exe ...

Comment: Mas o exe seria o meu, como o usuário poderia colocar ele em qualquer lugar, o programa procuraria a localização dele mesmo e verificaria suas subpastas

Comment: e então, ao teres a localização do ficheiro sabes onde se encontra as subpastas pertendidas

Comment: @BlanEmpt Lendo o titulo eu entendo uma coisa, lendo a pergunta eu entendo outra. Poderia deixar um exemplo de como gostaria??

Comment: Claro, eu quero saber como que faço para que o programa encontre a sua localização(no caso o executável). Resumindo, ele deve funcionar assim:

- Se localizar no computador.
- Verificar se as pastas e subpastas existem.

- Em caso de as pastas existirem:
 - Pegar todo o conteúdo de uma das subpastas.
 - Copiar e colar um outro diretório que já fora pré-definido.

- Em caso de não existir.
 - Criar pasta e Subpastas.
 - Mostrar na label que as pastas estão vazias.

Comment: Mas ai, ja é outra pergunta, a pergunta aqui é como criar pasta na mesma pasta do exe. Você precisa fazer outra pergunta para te responderem isso.

Comment: Mas isso só foi explicação a mais de como o programa funcionaria depois disso, minha única dúvida era em fazer o programa se localizar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor forma de garantir isso é pegando o diretorio do executável e depois juntando as pastas, da seguinte forma:

```
string dirPrograma = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

if(!Directory.Exist(Path.Combine(dirPrograma, "Downloads")))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(dirPrograma, "Downloads"));
```

Isso garante que, independente de onde o programa está sendo executado e seu diretorio base (chamando de um prompt de comando ou atalho com Diretório Base diferente), ele vai ser criado na pasta do programa.

Comment: Oh, compreendi e funcionou, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Suponhamos que o seu programa esteja no seguinte caminho

> C:\Users\JhonSnow\Documentos\GOT\got.exe

Para o programa verificar se existe a pasta dentro da pasta GOT

```
if(!Directory.Exist("Downloads"))
    Directory.CreateDirectory("Downloads");
```

Desta forma o sistema já vai entender que está na mesma pasta do executável, após isso o Diretorio GOT ficaria assim

- C:\

  - Users

    - JhonSnow

      - Documentos

        - GOT

          - Downloads
          - got.exe
          - got.exe.config

E mesmo que você mude a localização do programa a regra continua, ele sempre irá criar uma pasta onde está o executável.

Comment: Sim, exatamente isto

Comment: Errado. Se eu executar o programa de outra forma, por exemplo, ele vai criar na pasta de onde o programa foi executado. Se estou em um prompt de comando em c:\temp, mas o programa está em c:\program\p.exe, ele vai criar o arquivo em c:\temp.

Comment: De fato, esqueci deste porém... vlw